# Transferring File from Library to Library via Apex

Tags: apex, contentdocument

I'm writing an Aura Component that will display a list of Content Documents linked to both a record and a Library, and want to give users the ability to transfer the file from one Library to another. I am using the below controller code.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void transferFile(Id fileId, Id oldLibraryId, Id newLibraryId) {
    ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink(
        LinkedEntityId = newLibraryId,
        contentDocumentId = fileId
    );

    insert cdl;

    delete [SELECT Id FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId = :fileId AND LinkedEntityId = :libraryId];
}
```

FileId is the ID of the ContentDocument, OldLibraryId is the Id of the ContentWorkspace I'm moving the file from, and NewLibraryId is the Id of the ContentWorkspace I'm moving the file to. I get the following error on the "delete" line when I run the code:

```
DEPENDENCY_EXISTS, Cannot complete this operation. You cannot remove a document from its owning library.
```

I understand that there is also a table, ContentWorkspaceDoc, where the Ownership is specified, but the IsOwner field there is read-only and I get the same error if I try to delete that record.

Other questions and answers discuss how to add a document, but not how to remove it from the old library.

Is it possible to transfer a file from one Library to another via code? I understand it's doable via interface, but I want to make the file transfer as smooth as possible for my users. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a ParentId field on the ContentDocument system object that represents the ID of the library that owns the document. Could you update it to the new library ID before deleting the old one?

```
insert cdl;

ContentDocument contentDoc = new ContentDocument(Id=fileId, ParentId=newLibraryId);
update contentDoc;

delete [SELECT Id FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId = :fileId AND LinkedEntityId = :libraryId];
```

Comment: No such luck. It gives me an error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Parent ID: id value of incorrect type: 06A000000000000UAK (Id edited for security, Prefix is intact)

Comment: Sorry, I'd put the cdl.Id rather than the newLibraryId in the contentDoc variable - edited the answer with the change. Hope it works?

Comment: Yes! That's it! Thank you!